# Walk tree data structure to find its height and count elements in one loop

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a tree structure.

```
class Element {
    private List<Element> children;
}

Element treeStructure = produceSomeTreeStructure();
//How to get its height and number of elements.
```

Straight-forward solution is to make two loops. In first I can find number of nodes

[A question on getting number of nodes in a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791975/a-question-on-getting-number-of-nodes-in-a-binary-tree)
(change this algorithm for non-binary tree),

and the second loop to get the tree's height
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-method-to-find-height-of-binary-tree/

Again, adapt this algorithm to non-binary tree.

My question, how to do this in one walk. It is acceptable for me to keep results in global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know the number of nodes, then you'll need to explore the whole tree. The easiest way to do this is with a depth-first search, where you count the nodes as you go.

A depth-first search algorithm can also easily enough count the depth to which it's currently exploring, and the maximum depth reached overall. Modify the depth-first search algorithm to take both of these as arguments.

If you code it recursively (easiest), then you can simply add one to the depth argument every time you make a recursive call. And if this gives you a number that's greater than the maximum that you're keeping track of, then update the maximum to the current depth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that can be done as it is shown in the below code. Just add the counter `totalNodeCount` and do `+1` each time you traverse a node in BFS style.

```
// Iterative method to find height and node-count of Binary Tree
int treeHeightAndNumOfNodes(node *root)
{
    // Base Case
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Create an empty queue for level order tarversal
    queue<node *> q;

    // Enqueue Root and initialize height
    q.push(root);
    int height = 0;
    int totalNodeCount = 0; // <-- Use this counter to store total number of node traversed.

    while (1)
    {
        // nodeCount (queue size) indicates number of nodes
        // at current lelvel.
        int nodeCount = q.size();
        if (nodeCount == 0)
            return height;

        height++;

        // Dequeue all nodes of current level and Enqueue all
        // nodes of next level
        while (nodeCount > 0)
        {
            node *node = q.front();
            q.pop();
            if (node->left != NULL)
                q.push(node->left);
            if (node->right != NULL)
                q.push(node->right);
            nodeCount--;
            totalNodeCount++;    // <--  Update this counter
        }
    }
}
```

> Again, adapt this algorithm to non-binary tree.

To do that, replace the given below lines of codes with a loop that traverse through each child nodes and push the NON-NULL children into queue.

```
if (node->left != NULL)
    q.push(node->left);
if (node->right != NULL)
    q.push(node->right);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a bit like a BFS. You just have to walk your tree like the following:

```
int getHeight(Element e) {
    int max_height = 0;
    for (Element child : e.children) {
        max_height = max(max_height, getHeight(child));
    }
    return max_height + 1;
}
```

Similarly, getting the total number of elements is easy: instead of getting the maximum value among the node's children, you just add them up.

```
int getTotalCount(Element e) {
    int total_count = 0;
    for (Element child : e.children) {
        total_count += getTotalCount(el);
    }
    return total_count + 1;
}
```

If you must return the two numbers using the same function, just pack them in a common class to traverse your tree only once.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done. I made a class TreeData containing height and number of elements.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers.

And this is what I have coded.

```
public static TreeData countElementsAndFindHeight(Element root) {
    TreeData treePair = new TreeData();
    if (root == null) {
        return treePair;
    }

    treePair.nElements = 1;
    treePair.height = 1;

    //Nodes queue will contain all the elements of the trees, so its size is the number of elements.
    List<Element> nodesQueue = new LinkedList<Element>();

    treePair.walkedNodes = nodesQueue;

    List<Element> children = root.getChildren();
    if (CommonUtils.isCollectionEmpty(children)) {
        return treePair;
    }

    treePair.height = countElementsAndFindHeight(root, nodesQueue);
    nodesQueue.add(root);
    treePair.nElements = nodesQueue.size();

    return treePair;
}


private static int countElementsAndFindHeight(Element root, List<Element> nodesQueue) {
    int maxHeight = 1;
    List<Element> children = root.getChildren();
    if (CommonUtils.isCollectionEmpty(children)) {
        return maxHeight;
    }

    for (Element childElement : children) {
        int childHeight = countElementsAndFindHeight(childElement, nodesQueue);
        if (childHeight > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = childHeight;
        }
        nodesQueue.add(childElement);
    }

    return maxHeight + 1;
}

public static class TreeData {

    protected int height = 0;
    protected int nElements = 0;
}
```

Comment: Good work. This isn't really an answer to the question, though, and you're risking downvotes or bad karma on your account by posting it as an answer. You should really delete this answer yourself, and then choose one of the others as the accepted answer.

Comment: If you want to post your final code, you could edit your question and add at the bottom: **UPDATE: here is my final code...**